# LARAVEL - Get CSRF Token to login an user using my api

Tags: php, android, laravel, http, csrf

I am trying to login a user using laravel and the api I made for it, I made the post code with the email and password but it returns me a token mismatch error,i guess that's because I don't pass any csrf and my doubt is how to get it.

If I understood correctly I just need to do a GET on my main domain and grab the csrf from there, from the cookies (?).

I found this, but classes are deprecated and Ii dont know how to implement with my updated code:

Found:

```
    CookieStore cookieStore = httpClient.getCookieStore();
List <Cookie> cookies =  cookieStore.getCookies();
for (Cookie cookie: cookies) {
    if (cookie.getName().equals("XSRF-TOKEN")) {
        CSRFTOKEN = cookie.getValue();
    }
}
```

Need to implement the grab csrf part on my code:

```
url = new URL(AppConfig.BaseURL);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        // CookieStore cookieStore = connection.getCookieStore();
        // List<HttpCookie> cookies =  cookieStore.getCookies();
        // for (Cookie cookie: cookies) {
        //    if (cookie.getName().equals("XSRF-TOKEN")) {
        //        CSRFTOKEN = cookie.getValue();
        //    }
        // }
```

The commented is either wrong or deprecated but can't figure out how to solve it !

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In every page request we pass csrf token as a meta value in the head

```html
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

After that we simply use this meta value in javascript to set the X-CSRF-TOKEN header

```javascript
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', url);
request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
request.send(data);
```

Hope this helps for you

---

Edit: The header you are populating is probably wrong. For us it is X-CSRF-TOKEN instead of XSRF-TOKEN

Comment: I dont think thats what i need, i dont have any form, just an app.

Answer (score 0):

Use Laravel Passport for authenticate your API requests https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport configure it for listen password_grant types and in your APP use this library https://github.com/danielsz/android-oauth2-client for make Oauth2 Api calls